# How Draw rectangle in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need draw rectangle in canvas.
I know how to draw. But I did not get to do so would draw on a 360-degree

Example. blue, lilac, green they are one and the same rectangle, I changed the color for example
Red point is start position rectangle.

[image]

**EDIT:**

My actions:

LeftMouseDown in x=50;y=50 (press)
MoveMouse to 100;100 - now it works
MoveMouse to 30;150 or MoveMouse to 10;10  - Now I can not do this, but I need it

Comment: Do you mean you would like to know how to rotate a rectangle?

Comment: I have a feeling, he's trying to rotate in 3d

Comment: No! I want the mouse to draw a rectangle. But whatever it could draw in all directions

Comment: How would your rectangle start point be defined? On left mouse down?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Unless you need a rotated rectangle I wouldn't bother using transforms. Just set Left and Top to the minimum x and y and width to max-x and height maxy-y.

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" Background="Transparent" />
```

```
private Point startPoint;
private Rectangle rect;

private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    rect = new Rectangle
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect,startPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect,startPoint.Y);
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rect == null)
        return;

    var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
    var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

    var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
    var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

    rect.Width = w;
    rect.Height = h;

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
}

private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rect = null;
}
```

Comment: haven't understood how it happened. I just copy-pasted and it worked like magic. Now I've got to understand this. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much

Comment: oh that sneaky Background='Transparent'

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. On MouseLeftButtonDown: if you are not rotating: add a rectangle with its top left corner at the coordinates of the mouse and its height and width calculated by the difference between the top corner and the mouse coordinates. Set a boolean to true to indicate that you are drawing. if you are rotating: stop rotating by setting the rotating boolean to false.
2. On MouseMove: check if the left mouse button is still down and you are drawing (boolean from previous step). recalculate the width and height of the rectangle. If you are rotating adjust the rotation of the rectangle by calculating the angle between the point where you released the button, the RenderTransformOrigin and the current location of the mouse. (Use Vector.AngleBetween()
3. On MouseLeftButtonUp: if drawing is true set the drawing boolean to false and set a rotating boolean to true.

This flow will allow you to click (set a corner of the rectangle), drag and release to set the opposite corner, move the mouse to rotate the rectangle and click to fix the rectangle.

Place and rotate the rectangle by using RenderTransform: that will make things much easier than setting margins or Canvas.Left on the rectangle.

Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Erno, I this understand. But problem with Canvas.left\top. Transform - is good, and I'll be able to determine a click on the rectangle?

Comment: i am not quite sure what you are asking but the Rectangle has a MouseLeftButtonUp event.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to rotate as such - just adjust the height, width, and top-left of your rectangle based on your mouse position.

This is probably a good starting point for you:

**XAML:**

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"
        Background="White"
        IsHitTestVisible="True"
        MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown"
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
        MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp">
</Canvas>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    private bool _mouseDown = false;
    private Rectangle _current;
    private Point _initialPoint;

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _mouseDown = (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed) 
                                     && (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left);
        if (!_mouseDown)
            return;

        _current = new Rectangle();
        _initialPoint = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
        _current.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(_current);
    }
    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_mouseDown)
            return;

        Point position = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MyCanvas);
        _current.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,
                                         Math.Min(position.X, _initialPoint.X));
        _current.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,
                                         Math.Min(position.Y, _initialPoint.Y));
        _current.Width = Math.Abs(position.X - _initialPoint.X);
        _current.Height = Math.Abs(position.Y - _initialPoint.Y);
          }
    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
            _mouseDown = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();

            mainCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown);
            mainCanvas.MouseLeftButtonUp+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MainPage_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            mainCanvas.MouseMove+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(MainPage_MouseMove);

            SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

            _curRectangle.Rect.Stroke = myBrush;
            _curRectangle.Rect.StrokeThickness = 4;
            _curRectangle.Rect.Fill = myBrush;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        }

        private void elipse_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        }
        RealRect _curRectangle = null;
        private void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _curRectangle = new RealRect((int)e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas).X, (int)e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas).Y, false);
            mainCanvas.Children.Insert(0, _curRectangle.Rect);
            _curRectangle.StartRect();
        }

        private void MainPage_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_curRectangle != null)
            {
                _curRectangle.ClearStartTemp();
                _curRectangle = null;
            }

        }

        private void MainPage_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_curRectangle != null)
            {
                _curRectangle.EndX = (int)e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas).X;
                _curRectangle.EndY = (int)e.GetPosition(sender as Canvas).Y;
                _curRectangle.MakeReal();
            }

            //exampleRectangle.Rect.Width =  - Canvas.GetLeft(exampleRectangle.Rect);
            //exampleRectangle.Rect.Height =  - Canvas.GetTop(exampleRectangle.Rect);
        }
    }
}
```

Work class

```
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public static readonly Point Empty;
        public Point(int x, int y) { _x = x; _y = y; }
        int _x;

        public int X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set { _x = value; }
        }
        int _y;

        public int Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set { _y = value; }
        }
    }
    public class RealRect
    {
        Rectangle mRect = new Rectangle();

        #region Class Local Variables

        private SilverlightApplication1.Point mStart;

        public SilverlightApplication1.Point MStart
        {
            get { return mStart; }
            set { mStart = value; }
        }
        private SilverlightApplication1.Point mEnd;
        private SilverlightApplication1.Point mRealStart;
        private SilverlightApplication1.Point mRealEnd;
        private System.Windows.Size mRealSize;
        private bool isStatus = false;

        public bool IsStatus
        {
            get { return isStatus; }
            set { isStatus = value; }
        }
        private SilverlightApplication1.Point mTempPoint;

        #endregion


        public RealRect(int x, int y, bool start)
        {
            mTempPoint = new SilverlightApplication1.Point(x, y);
            IsStatus = false;
            mEnd = Point.Empty;
            mRealEnd = Point.Empty;
        }
        public void ClearStartTemp()
        {
            IsStatus = false;
            mTempPoint = Point.Empty;
        }
        public void StartRect()
        {
            IsStatus = true;
            mStart = mTempPoint;
            mRealStart = mTempPoint;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Ending X Value of rectangle
        /// </summary>
        public int EndX
        {
            set { mEnd.X = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ending Y Value of rectangle
        /// </summary>
        public int EndY
        {
            set { mEnd.Y = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the corrected rectangle
        /// </summary>
        public Rectangle Rect
        {
            get
            {
                MakeReal();

                return mRect;

            }
        }

        public void MakeReal()
        {
            //Started top left, ended bottom right
            if (mEnd.X > mStart.X && mEnd.Y > mStart.Y)
            {
                mRealStart = mStart;
                mRealEnd = mEnd;
                mRealSize = new Size(mRealEnd.X - mRealStart.X, mRealEnd.Y - mRealStart.Y);
               // return;
            }

            //Started bottom right, ended top left
            else if (mEnd.X < mStart.X && mEnd.Y < mStart.Y)
            {
                mRealEnd = mStart;
                mRealStart = mEnd;
                mRealSize = new Size(mRealEnd.X - mRealStart.X, mRealEnd.Y - mRealStart.Y);
               // return;
            }

            //Started top right left, ended bottom left
            else if (mEnd.X < mStart.X && mEnd.Y > mStart.Y)
            {
                mRealStart.X = mEnd.X;
                mRealStart.Y = mStart.Y;
                mRealEnd.X = mStart.X;
                mRealEnd.Y = mEnd.Y;
                mRealSize = new Size(mRealEnd.X - mRealStart.X, mRealEnd.Y - mRealStart.Y);
               // return;
            }

            //Started bottom left, ended top right
            else if (mEnd.X > mStart.X && mEnd.Y < mStart.Y)
            {
                mRealStart.X = mStart.X;
                mRealStart.Y = mEnd.Y;
                mRealEnd.X = mEnd.X;
                mRealEnd.Y = mStart.Y;
                mRealSize = new Size(mRealEnd.X - mRealStart.X, mRealEnd.Y - mRealStart.Y);
               // return;
            }
            Canvas.SetLeft(mRect, mRealStart.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(mRect, mRealStart.Y);
            mRect.Width = mRealSize.Width;
            mRect.Height = mRealSize.Height;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, this is solution for UWP. (based on @Kris answer).

It works for mouse, touch and pen.

**Code behind:**

```
private Point startPoint;
private Rectangle rect;

private void canvas_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas).Position;
    rect = new Rectangle()
    {
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral),
        StrokeThickness = 5
    };

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, startPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, startPoint.Y);
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
}

private void canvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Pointer.IsInContact || rect == null)
        return;

    var pos = e.GetCurrentPoint(canvas).Position;

    var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
    var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

    var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
    var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

    rect.Width = w;
    rect.Height = h;

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
}

private void canvas_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rect = null;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" PointerPressed="canvas_PointerPressed" PointerMoved="canvas_PointerMoved" PointerReleased="canvas_PointerReleased" Background="Transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Polygon Points="25,0 5,30 45,30"
         Fill="Red"
         Stroke="Black"
         StrokeThickness="2" />
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I'm wrong but I think this can work :

```
      <Rectangle Width="200" Height="50" Fill="Black">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="45"></RotateTransform>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>
```