# How to recognize if a rectangle contains a Text block within in

Tags: c#, wpf, contains, textblock

I'm creating this program in which the user drags/drops a text block into a rectangle, and then store the contents of that specific textblock when he/she drops it into the rectangle.

I figured out how to do the drag/drop, but I just can't figure out how to check if the rectangle contains the textblock.

Here's the code so far:

```
bool captured = false;
double x_shape, x_canvas, y_shape, y_canvas;
UIElement source = null;



private void shape_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  source = (UIElement)sender;
  Mouse.Capture(source);
  captured = true;
  x_shape = Canvas.GetLeft(source);
  x_canvas = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).X;
  y_shape = Canvas.GetTop(source);
  y_canvas = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).Y;
}

private void shape_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (captured)
  {
    double x = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).X;
    double y = e.GetPosition(LayoutRoot).Y;
    x_shape += x - x_canvas;
    Canvas.SetLeft(source, x_shape);
    x_canvas = x;
    y_shape += y - y_canvas;
    Canvas.SetTop(source, y_shape);
    y_canvas = y;
  }
}

private void shape_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  Mouse.Capture(null);
  captured = false;
}



private void rectangle1_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.Capture(null))
    {
        textBox1.Text = "test";


    }
}
```

The "Shape" events apply to the textblock by the way, just for clarification. 
I tried to find a shortcut and make it so with the rectangle1_MouseEnter event that if the mouse isn't clicked, then store the values (didn't include the code for the storing values). However, the problem is, this idea doesn't work because textBox1.Text="test" isn't registered, and I don't see why it isn't.

Comment: Could someone please guide me?

Comment: Are you adding textblock control to rectangle or canvas.

Comment: I added a textblock to the canvas, and it can currently be dragged and dropped. I know that the System.drawing rectangle class can use the IntersectWith(), but that's only between 2 rectangles.  Is there a way to dynamically create a system.DRAWING rectangle? Because I've tried and google'd, but there's nothing on dynamically creating a .drawing rectangle in WPF

Comment: Please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059894/how-draw-rectangle-in-wpf