# create a little 2d game with c# displayed in wpf

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I want to create a little "game" in c#. For the game I need a field, where you can move. Now I want to create a 2d array (or 2d list) and display it with wpf, but I dont know how. I want to set the field size in C# and generate the gamefield random in C#.

**Can someone of you give me a hint, how I can display a 2d array (or 2 list) in wpf and fill the cells with different colors?**

It would be nice if you can show me a little code snipped (for understanding maybe).

Here is a little pic:

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TgQT.png)

I searched a lot, but didn't find something usefull.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059894/how-draw-rectangle-in-wpf https://www.google.com/

Comment: look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276808/how-to-populate-a-wpf-grid-based-on-a-2-dimensional-array